# Use of "the" among list of proper names

Tags: grammar

When listing proper nouns in a sentence, must I use "the" before each proper noun, or can the first "the" constitute for the remaining nouns?

Example:

...the Department of Transportation, the Consumer Product Safety Commission, the National Institute on Standards and Technology, and the Food and Drug Administration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "the" is needed for each one to show they are separate and not one department of all of those things.

If they all started with "The Department of" you could use "The Departments of" for the first one and just list the rest of the name for each subsequent one but with some being departments and some being councils, institutes, and administrations the "the" is needed each time.